# How can I import xhr-mock module right?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, xmlhttprequest

I have a problem with `xhr-mock` import (I'm using Jest framework). I have an exercise in which I must test a simple function that use `XMLHttprequest`. In order to do this I use the `xhr-mock` module and use 'setup' method in order to replace the global `XMLHttpRequest` object with the `MockXMLHttpRequest`. When I call 'setup' method from test I get the error: mockXHR.setup is not a function. Below there is my code.

```js
const mockXHR = require('xhr-mock');
const { exampleFunction } = require('../function/exampleXHR');

describe('exampleXHR', () => {
    beforeEach(() => mockXHR.setup());

    test('xhr test', () => {
        exampleFunction();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

For commonJS, use it like this:

```js
var xhrMock = require("xhr-mock").default;

console.log(xhrMock.setup)
```

See: https://runkit.com/embed/gyrys612q3a2